# Issue trying to launch sample project che-ide-server-extension

Tags: docker, keycloak, eclipse-che

With Eclipse Che, I've recently been able to deploy the docker container without any issue as provided in the instructions.

I'm at the point where am trying to learn a bit more about extension development for Che, and I'm going through the small introduction on "developing your first plugin" located on the following page:
https://www.eclipse.org/che/docs/che-in-che-quickstart.html

I'm stuck at the point where I can successfully build and deploy the sample project by executing the *Traefik Start*, *Tomcat8-IDE Start*, *Deploy IDE* and *Deploy Workspace Agent* commands.

But when it comes time to navigate to the newly created 2nd workspace by clicking on the link provided in the IDE to go to the newly created 2nd workplace instance...:

[image]
... I end up getting redirected to the following error page:
  [image]
I suspect that there may be some kind of configuration problem with the sample plugin project, or configuration problem with keycloak, but I'm at the point where I don't really know how to proceed in terms of troubleshooting.

(Update: 2018/07/31)

At request of @kalrsson for more information, below is a screenshot of the che-public client configuration in my Keycloak instance.
[image]

(***SOLUTION*** Update: 2018/08/01)

Thanks to @kalrsson for pointing me in the right direction. 
At first I tried only adding the needed URL to the "Valid Redirect URIs" list. Doing so allowed me to get past the issue were I was receiving the error "Invalid parameter: redirect_uri". However, this only presented me with a blank page. On this blank page, when I inspect the web browser console, I noticed the following error:
[image]

From there, I also tried to add the needed URL to WebOrigins in KeyCloak as seen below.
[image]

Doing this finally allowed me to fully load and render the secondary workspace

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you go to keycloak_ip:5050/auth, login as admin/admin, clients, che-public, and the IP you use to redirect urls and webOrigins?

So, you need to previewURL:port both to redirectURIs and webOrigins

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I just edited my post with a screenshot of the information you are asking for. So far for the "Valid Reirect URIs" setting, i use "192.168.103:8080/*" and for "Web Origins" i use "192.168.56.103:8080".

Comment: Adding the previewURL:port both to redirectURIs and webOrigins resolved the issue. Thanks!  :)